# Can it be proven that $((A\setminus B)\cup C) = (A \cup C) \setminus B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can it be proven that a union of a set outside of a complement can be moved next to the set that's being complemented? I want to prove $(A\setminus B)\cup C = (A \cup C) \setminus B$

I believe I would need to show show that an element of the first is an element of the second and that an element of the second is an element of the first. The shows that they're subsets of each other, hence they're equal.

suppose $x \in (A\setminus B)\cup C$

$\implies (x \in A\ \ and\ \ x \notin B)\ \ or\ \ x \in C$

$\implies (x \in A\ \ or\ \ x \in C)\ \ and\ \ x \notin B$ <--- I want to say that this statement is true, but the truth tables of booleans x, y, and y reveal that $((x\ \ and\ \ y)\ \ or\ \ z) \ne ((x\ \ or\ \ z)\ \ and\ \ y))$

$\implies x \in (A \cup C) \setminus B$

I would then apply the same logic backwards

Comment: Take $A=C$ and $B$ a proper subset of $A$.

Comment: "I want to say that this is true, but ... ." This is a clue that it's time to think again about what you want to prove.

Comment: False assertions are often more difficult to prove than true assertions.

Comment: Is this clause really true? I seriously doubt. Assume the three sets have a non-null intersection, then the element x, which is in this intersection, is in the set $(A \backslash B) \cup C$ but is not in set $(A \cup C) \backslash B$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this clause really true? I seriously doubt. Assume the three sets have a non-null intersection, then the element x, which is in this intersection, is in the set (∖)∪ but is not in set (∪)∖

Comment: I see. Good counterexample.